# Converting large Pandas Dataframe from "sparse" float to int

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, nan

I am receiving Pandas DataFrame from an upstream component that has a large number of columns (~20000), all of them have dtypes `float64` and most of the entries are `NaN` (this is *bag of words* encoded document). Example:

```
1   2.0 NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN 1.0 NaN 4.0 NaN 1.0 NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I need to convert this dataframe to dense `int`s for further processing (`int8` is sufficient in this case). I know that in Pandas, you can convert and fill the missing values like this

```
df.fillna(0).astype(np.int8)
```

The problem is that as soon as the code starts filling the missing values, it very quickly overflows the memory and crashes.

At the moment, I am saving the Dataframe on disk and processing it with another script, line-by-line (converting floats to ints and replacing NaNs with 0s), which is then read again by Pandas as `int8` (`pd.read_csv("preprocessed.csv", dtype=np.int8)`).

The result (dataframe containing `int8` values) fits into memory.

My question - Is there some efficient way of doing this transformation in Pandas (converting `float64` into `int8` while replacing NaNs with 0s) without overflowing memory? (both original and desired dataframes fit into memory, it is just that the above-mentioned Pandas code doesn't)

Comment: Does `df.fillna(0).astype(int)` perform better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a limit on the memory. In which case, try not to chain the operation. That is:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df.astype('int8')
```

Or use `apply` on the rows if you have less rows than columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0).astype('int8'), axis=1)
```

However, Since most of the cells in the csv file are the empty string, I think you might be better of doing:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype='str')
```

Comment: @MatusDubrava also try `apply` on columns since that changes the `dtype` of the columns as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do the conversion in blocks instead of all at once

- start with heavy dataframe A
- create a new dataframe B
- copy range from A to new dataframe C (choose block size to not overrun memory)
- convert range in C to desired type (can be combined with former step)
- delete old range in A
- join C to A
- repeat until all ranges are converted